# A Series of Wars

Tags: riddle

> We come from two different factions, as unlike as can be.
>   We support the factions' armies, but not necessarily our own.
>
> At the start of the war, half of us supported nobody.
>   Those remaining were split between supporting their own faction and
>   supporting the opposing faction.
>
> As the war commenced, our allegiances changed.
>   We supported whichever army was passing through at the time.
>   As casualties mounted, more and more of us ceased supporting anybody at all.
>
> Finally, one side was victorious, but our lives were unaffected.
>   We merely wait for the next war, which will play out differently, but the
>   same.

Who are we?

Comment: Ha, I thought for sure it was the United States electorate...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We are

> Chessboard squares, which are black and white (like chess pieces) but support (physically) whatever piece is standing on it at the moment, regardless of its color

Comment: Haha wow, 3 minutes! Too easy I guess. How far into the riddle did you get before you figured it out?

Comment: @VictorHenry: it's ok, I play "what, where, when" competitively :) Can't tell exactly how far I got, probably "supported nobody" put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are

> A deck of Cards, in the game of War.

```
We come from two different factions, as unlike as can be.
We support the factions' armies, but not necessarily our own.
```

> The deck is split up at the start of the game, between the two players. The cards don't have their own army, in a sense.

```
At the start of the war, half of us supported nobody.
Those remaining were split between supporting their own faction and supporting the opposing faction.
```

> Again, deck is split in half and dealt to each player. They support each player, but only when getting played.

```
As the war commenced, our allegiances changed.
We supported whichever army was passing through at the time.
As casualties mounted, more and more of us ceased supporting anybody at all.
```

> As the game plays, cards go from all the players to one, on each hand. They are passed around continuously until one player has the whole deck.

```
Finally, one side was victorious, but our lives were unaffected.
We merely wait for the next war, which will play out differently, but the same.
```

> When a player wins, the cards are put back, and can be used for another "war", as long as it was not a violent game that bent the cards.